# Fail to start Flink SQL client on EMR on EKS docker image

Tags: java, docker, apache-flink, amazon-emr, flink-sql

I'm playing with the Flink docker image of EMR on EKS - *public.ecr.aws/emr-on-eks/flink/emr-6.15.0-flink:latest*. When I try to start the SQL client, I see the following error. (I don't see this error when I use the official flink image.)

```
06:33:00.495 [main] ERROR org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient - SQL Client must stop. Unexpected exception. This is a bug. Please consider filing an issue.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find a free permitted port on the machine.
        at org.apache.flink.util.NetUtils.getAvailablePort(NetUtils.java:177) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1-amzn-1.jar:1.17.1-amzn-1]
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient$EmbeddedGateway.create(SqlClient.java:257) ~[flink-sql-client-1.17.1-amzn-1.jar:1.17.1-amzn-1]
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.start(SqlClient.java:108) ~[flink-sql-client-1.17.1-amzn-1.jar:1.17.1-amzn-1]
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:228) [flink-sql-client-1.17.1-amzn-1.jar:1.17.1-amzn-1]
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.main(SqlClient.java:179) [flink-sql-client-1.17.1-amzn-1.jar:1.17.1-amzn-1]
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClientException: Unexpected exception. This is a bug. Please consider filing an issue.
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:242)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.main(SqlClient.java:179)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find a free permitted port on the machine.
        at org.apache.flink.util.NetUtils.getAvailablePort(NetUtils.java:177)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient$EmbeddedGateway.create(SqlClient.java:257)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.start(SqlClient.java:108)
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:228)
        ... 1 more
```

It looks to be caused by the `getAvailablePort()` of the *NetUtils* class (*NetUtils.java*).

```java
public static Port getAvailablePort() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0)) {
            int port = serverSocket.getLocalPort();
            if (port != 0) {
                FileLock fileLock = new FileLock(NetUtils.class.getName() + port);
                if (fileLock.tryLock()) {
                    return new Port(port, fileLock);
                } else {
                    fileLock.unlockAndDestroy();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Could not find a free permitted port on the machine.");
}
```

I see a related Jira ticket (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-28613) and it seems to be resolved by changing file permission. However it doesn't work for me. Basically I'm not sure why it fails to do FileLock on the `/tmp` folder.

Could you please inform me how I may be able to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I checked `sql-client.sh` further and it writes to `/mnt/tmp` rather than `/tmp`. Creating the temporary directory before hand fixed the issue and I created a custom Docker image by adding the following.

```
RUN mkdir -p /mnt/tmp
```

It would affect not only the SQL client but also other places where `getAvailablePort()` is applied. Therefore it's necessary to update the Docker image.